# Calculating the equivalent resistance

Tags: resistors

Consider following circuit made of n resistors with r resistivity like as a mobious strip

I want to find a recurrence equation for equivalent resistor in terms of r and vs.
In other words, An equation for equivalent resistor between Req(n+1) and Req(n)

And I want to find Thevenin circuit between A and B.

I think I should use source splitting for Vs. While I don't know how!?

[image]

Comment: Equivalent resistor...and what?

Comment: Sound like a school assignment.

Comment: @Oldfart Yes it is. But I don't have any idea to solve it. I don't want complete solution. I just want a hint.

Comment: @Bart thevenin equivalent circuit

Comment: Are all of the resistors equal? If so, what does symmetry tell you about the Thévenin voltage?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Comment: @Sania Sadian, hint: you can edit the question to add the missing part.

Comment: Take n = 0, find Req(0), then find Req(1),you'll see pattern

Comment: @Deep for n=1, I'll find Req(1)=r/2. Is it right?

Comment: Mobius strip has only one wire. So, the resistors are shortened, and equivalent resistance is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a hint: Draw out the complete circuit for the N=1 case (5 resistors). Put the voltage source with its positive terminal at the top of the diagram and the negative terminal at the bottom. Does this circuit look at all familiar?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frakH0.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: No. It doesn't look familiar. maybe I can't draw It well. Can you draw it?

Comment: Hint (and some history): It is Samuel Hunter Christie's 'diamond' method.

Comment: for this shape, I will find equivalent resistance r/2. (all of 5 resistors have equal resistivity "r"). Is it true !? So I can find thevenin circuit by simplifying the resistors. I think for every n the thevenin voltage is the same!?

Comment: Yes, the resistance between A and B is r/2 for N=1. And yes, the Thévenin voltage is the same for all N.

Comment: Ok. Now I can find equivalent resistor. But I don't know how to connect Nth case to (N-1)th case for induction. And also Thevenin resistivity.